# Ubuntu 9.04: Pecl extension downloads but does not install

Tags: php, ubuntu, installation, pecl

I'm new to php, so apologies if I've overlooked something simple. I want to install the php extension pecl_http. I have followed the instructions here http://www.mkfoster.com/2009/01/04/how-to-install-a-php-pecl-extensionmodule-on-ubuntu/, specifically:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear 
sudo apt-get install php5-dev 
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-openssl-dev
```

which all works fine. However, the next step does not seem to complete:

```
sudo pecl install pecl_http
```

All this does is download the .tgz, but doesn't actually install it. It puts the file here:

```
/build/buildd/php5-5.2.10.dfsg.1/pear-build-download/pecl_http-1.7.0.tgz
```

I can unpack it myself, but have a feeling there may be more to installing it. Indeed, doing:

```
pecl list
```

tells me no extensions installed. What am I not doing?

Thanks.

**Edit:** I've found these alternatives to installing a pecl extension: https://serverfault.com/questions/178986/pecl-install-uploadprogress-fails-silently However it breaks on build:

```
install: cannot stat `tmp/modules5/pecl-http.so': No such file or directory
```

for the simple reason the lib is called `http.so`, not `pecl-http.so`...

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 has a readymade php-http package. However in your case, you should try the manual build step with `sudo pecl build ...` after extracting that tarball. It's possible that `install` suppressed the failure reason.

Comment: Okay, if you got the `http.so` somehow, then just copy it yourself to /usr/lib/php/*, and manually add it to your php.ini - pecl install does nothing more.

Comment: @mario, thanks, I'll give these a whirl

Comment: @mario: I've done this: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/pyrus.commands.build.php but make test fails on HttpRequest, kind of fundamental :) Tried everything, at a loss.

Comment: What I usually prefer is to install PHP-dev by apt-get but pecl and pear packages through pecl/pear.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to debug the process by adding `-v` or `-vvv` to the `pecl` command.

Can you provide output?